# iOS swift quickblox integration

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox

[image]I am implementing social media application in which i want to add chat feature. So I have decided to use quickblox sdk. I am implementing ios application in swift language. For integration i have followed same steps which is mentioned in quickblox document. But still shows me so many errors. (http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework)

Can you please help me on this.

Thanks In advance

Comment: can u show ur errors

Comment: are u using pod or .framework?

Comment: Nope I am not using pop. I am trying to integrate demo app "sample-chat-swift" in my code

Comment: @ Reshmi Majumder : Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik do you have any idea?

Comment: ya already worked in one app with quickblox , thats y i asked

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik have you worked on objective-c or swift language?

Comment: @both, in objective - C the app is in live name **Tapr.**, in swift **CIM** is not in live

Comment: I am getting <Bolts/Bolts.h> file not found error in swift.Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can you please advice me how to integrate chat sample code in our swift project...Because I am getting missing file error or file not found error as i mentioned above. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: can your show error, with out error how do i support bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  <Bolts/Bolts.h> file not found error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have added error screen shot. Please have a look.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik If you can address me steps that would be great...

Answer (score 0):

`QM services` has been deprecated and removed from current version of Quickblox samples.

QuickBlox chat sample in Swift is available [here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift). Please check it as a reference, and here is the iOS SDK [documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API) that covers the setup process.